# Given three positive numbers $x,y,z$. Prove that $(x+y-z)(\frac{3}{x+y}-\frac{1}{y+z}-\frac{1}{z+x})\leqq\frac{1}{2}$ .

Tags: inequality, polynomials, fractions, alternative-proof

> Given three positive numbers $x, y, z$. Prove that
>   $$(x+ y- z)\left ( \frac{3}{x+ y}- \frac{1}{y+ z}- \frac{1}{z+ x} \right )\leqq \frac{1}{2}$$

**First solution.** *Subtracting* $(\!x+ y- z\!)(\!\frac{3}{x+ y}- \frac{1}{y+ z}- \frac{1}{z+ x}\!)$ *from* $1\div 2$, *we have the following one*:
$$\frac{(x+ 2y)(z+ x- 2y)^{2}+ 2(4x+ 5y+ 18z)(x+ y- 2z)^{2}+ 30y(y- z)^{2}+ 39x(x- z)^{2}}{48(x+ y)(y+ z)(z+ x)}\geqq 0$$
How about another solution? I hope to see that. Thanks!

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source of the problem, its motivation, your thoughts on the problem in addition to any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Dear  @Carl Mummert. See please better the question. You can see there the context, the source of the problem, motivation and thoughts on the problem. What is your trying? I am sure that you have a beautiful solution of this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
If $x+y\leqslant z$ the inequality is obvious*. Else we may write it as
$$\frac3{x+y}\leqslant \frac1{x+z}+\frac1{y+z}+\frac1{2x+2y-2z}$$

which easily follows from Jensen’s inequality.

—
PS: In case not so obvious,
$$\frac1{x+z}+\frac1{y+z} \leqslant \frac1{2x+y} + \frac1{x+2y} \leqslant \frac2{x+y}$$

Comment: For $x+y\leq z$ we need to prove that $\frac{3}{x+y}\geq\frac{1}{x+z}+\frac{1}{y+z},$ which is indeed true. We can end it also by C-S. Nice solution! +1.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, perhaps proving positivity of the second bracket is not so obvious.

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that $f(z)\geq0$, where 
$$f(z)=6z^3-3(x+y)z^2-3(x^2+y^2)z+2x^3+x^2y+xy^2+2y^3.$$
Now, $$f'(z)=3(6z^2-2(x+y)z-x^2-y^2),$$ which gives
$$z_{min}=\frac{x+y+\sqrt{7x^2+7y^2+2xy}}{6}$$ and we need to prove that
$$f\left(z_{min}\right)\geq0,$$ which is smooth.

Indeed, $f\left(z_{min}\right)\geq0$ gives
$$2(13x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+13y^3)\geq\sqrt{(7x^2+7y^2+2xy)^3}.$$
Let $x^2+y^2=2kxy.$

Hence, $k\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$4(x+y)^2(13x^2+13y^2-10xy)^2\geq(7x^2+7y^2+2xy)^3$$ or
$$4(k+1)(13k-5)^2\geq(7k+1)^3$$ or
$$(k-1)(37k^2+38k-11)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.